# Typescript generics, Type 'X' is not assignable to type 'Y'

Tags: typescript, generics

I have the following piece of code:

```
interface DummyTableRow {
    id: number;
    name: string;
}
interface RowChange<Row extends object> {
    newRow: Row | null;
    oldRow: Row | null;
}
interface RowChangeBag {
    Dummy: RowChangeList<DummyTableRow>;
}
type RowChangeList<Row extends object> = Array<RowChange<Row>>;

function add<
    Row extends object,
    T extends keyof RowChangeBag,
    // error on next line: Type 'DummyTableRow' is not assignable to type 'Row'.
    L extends RowChangeList<Row> = RowChangeBag[T]
    >(
    bag: RowChangeBag,
    tableName: T,
    newRow: Row | null,
    oldRow: Row | null,
) {
    bag[tableName].push({ newRow, oldRow });
}
```

Why does it complain? Why is `DummyTableRow` not assignable to `Row`?

Or could this be a 'bug' in typescript? (i use version 2.6.2 for this example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a TypeScript bug.

The behavior you saw can be reduced to the following:

```
interface DummyTableRow {
    id: number;
    name: string;
}

function doing<Row>() {
    let a: DummyTableRow
    let b: Row
    // error on next line: Type 'DummyTableRow' is not assignable to type 'Row'.
    b = a
}
```

The issue here is that since `Row` is a generic type, there is no way the compiler can tell whether `a` can be assigned to `b`, because `b` can be any type defined at usage, e.g.

```
doing<{ a: string }>()
```

Comment: any idea on how to model this thing any other way then?

Comment: it depends on what exactly do you want to do. The general idea is to move the concrete type (`DummyTableRow`) into the input. Your `add()` function should not be constraint by it.

Comment: On the other hand, if your `add()` function needs to be constraint by it (as the question on SO is just an example), you can move it into the base of `Row` (i.e. `Row extends DummyTableRow`) and use `RowChangeBag<Row>` instead.

Comment: ok thank you! I think i get it! I guess i'll remodel! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your code is mixing two types with similar names but their are not compatibles:

- `DummyTableRow` is your abstraction of the row → ok
- The generic type constraint `Row extends object`: `object` is not compatible with `DummyTableRow`: `id` and `name` properties are missing. → Just do `Row extends DummyTableRow`.

Other issues:

- `RowChangeBag` has to be generic too.
- `RowChangeBag` is meant to store several `RowChangeList`, cf. `T extends keyof RowChangeBag` and `bag[tableName]` is a `RowChangeList`. In the code below, I've split it into 2 interfaces, so that it will be easier to add tables in it.
- The `L` generic type constraint in the `add` method is not used.

My advices to enhance the code readibility:

- Prefer generic type names starting with `T`: `Row`→`TRow`
- Then, `DummyTableRow` name can be simplified: just `Row`
- Avoid using `null`; use only `undefined`.
- Then, define property as optional rather than nullable.
- Use `T[]` rather than `Array<T>` because it's shorter and more JavaScript idiomatic.

Fix proposal (tested on the [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20Row%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20id%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20RowChange%3CTRow%20extends%20Row%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20newRow%3F%3A%20TRow%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20oldRow%3F%3A%20TRow%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20RowChangeList%3CTRow%20extends%20Row%3E%20%3D%20RowChange%3CTRow%3E%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20RowChangeBag%3CTRow%20extends%20Row%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5Bname%3A%20string%5D%3A%20RowChangeList%3CTRow%3E%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20add%3C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20TRow%20extends%20Row%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20T%20extends%20keyof%20RowChangeBag%3CTRow%3E%0D%0A%3E(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20bag%3A%20RowChangeBag%3CTRow%3E%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20tableName%3A%20T%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20newRow%3A%20TRow%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20oldRow%3A%20TRow%2C%0D%0A)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20bag%5BtableName%5D.push(%7B%20newRow%2C%20oldRow%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%7D)):

```
interface Row {
    id: number;
    name: string;
}

interface RowChange<TRow extends Row> {
    newRow?: TRow;
    oldRow?: TRow;
}

type RowChangeList<TRow extends Row> = RowChange<TRow>[];

interface TableGroup<T> {
    Table1: T;
    Table2: T;
}

interface RowChangeBag<TRow extends Row>
    extends TableGroup<RowChangeList<TRow>> { }

function add<
    TRow extends Row,
    TKey extends keyof RowChangeBag<TRow>
>(
    bag: RowChangeBag<TRow>,
    tableName: TKey,
    newRow: TRow,
    oldRow: TRow,
) {
    bag[tableName].push({ newRow, oldRow });
}
```

Comment: Well, `Row` can be anything, that's why it's an object, in this example `DummyRow` has `id` and `name` but this is absolutely not true for any row, or for the real-world scenario.

As for the rest, there is nothing wrong with using `null`. In mij case, becasue rows have to be serialized at some point, and we have to keep track of deleted rows, we have to use `null` (`undefined` is not JSON). 

unional already answered the question, but still thank you for your answer!